# Angularjs nested ng-controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a DOM like this:

```
<md-content class="timelineContainer" ng-controller="modelCtrl" layout-padding flex>
......
     <div ng-controller="objectCtrl">
       <md-button aria-label="Favorite model" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
          <ng-md-icon icon="favorite" size="28" aria-label="Favorite model"></ng-md-icon>ADD TO FAVORITES
       </md-button>
     </div>
......
</md-content>
```

I thought that from inners controllers (in this case **objectCtrl**), could get access to parent controllers (in this case **modelCtrl**) via $scope, but not.

What's the way to accomplish this?

Comment: For what exactly are you trying to do it?

Comment: Get info from parent controller.

Comment: so you want to access a variable of the parent controller for example?

Comment: Yes. At least I discovered it via $scope.$parent.$parent, but I do not understand why $.parent.$parent instead of $parent.

Comment: you could use the methods `$broadcast` and `$on`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with adding "$parent." before the variable in the view

Comment: I display via console console.log($scope.$parent) from within objectCtrl but do not see any variable from modelCtrl.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. It's in $scope.$parent.$parent.  I do not understand why the additional level up.

Comment: so you could access in the view but isn't the best practice

Answer (score 0):

You can most definitely access parent controllers from child controllers.
 Angular `$scope` follows the [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) pattern, which can cause a lot of confusion if you don't understand how it works.

Can't guide you any more than this however because your example is incomplete. As the other answer states you will probably find it in `$parent`.